# Rails multiple condition query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have a LineItem class which belongs to an order. An order has many line items. An order has two attributes, service_category and state. I need to get all orders that have the below conditions. Currently I am using the below 2 queries but I really want to just use 1 query, is this possible?

```
LineItem.includes(:order).where(
   menu_item_id:menu_item_id,
   orders:{
     service_category: "delivery",
     state:["pending", "open"]
    }
  )  

LineItem.includes(:order).where(
   menu_item_id:menu_item_id,
   orders:{
     service_category: "walkup",
     state:["pending", "closed"]
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the exact syntax since I don't have the models set up, but shouldn't you be able to include both states separated by an OR (||)? Have you tried something like this?

```
LineItem.includes(:order).where(
   menu_item_id:menu_item_id,
   orders:{
     (service_category: "delivery",
     state:["pending", "open"])
     ||
     (service_category: "walkup",
     state:["pending", "closed"])
    }
  )
```